# Microsoft Excel C API and Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, excel, api

I am trying to figure out the best solution to a rather complicated problem.  I need to be able to publish data from a database as a webpage dashboard.  I am not allowed to query the database directly except through a program called Xtraction.  However, Xtraction has the ability to export queried data to MS Excel.

I am wondering anyone can tell me whether the C API for Excel will allow me to grab the data in Excel and use Excel's native charting functionality to produce the rich charts I need to post on the webpage.  Right now, the only way I know to explore this is by getting MS Visual Studio 2010 and I don't want to put out the money if it's not going to be able to do this for me.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C api will only allow you to write UDFs. For your purposes- charting etc - you will need to use automation.

Before you go overboard and buy VS 2010, there are a few options you can explore -
1. Get VS 2010 Express - this is the free edition. Then code using C++/COM or C#/Excel Interop.
2. Use Excel VBA - it's built into excel itself. Just Press Alt-F11. It will open up the VBA development environment. You can then go about creating a VBA add-in (.xlam) and write VBA code there that creates graphs.

However you create the graphs, exporting them to the file system is as easy as

```
ActiveChart.Export Filename:=<file name>, FilterName:="GIF"
```

Note: The above is VBA code.

Edit: If you decide to go with the excel vba route - you should consider looking at the Macro Recorder. It generates code for the actions that you perform on the UI - it is a fantastic productivity boost and gets your initial code up and running in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand whether your code will be part of a web application that's concurrently access by several users or whether it is a sort of batch job that extracts and delivers data that's published on a web site.

Anyhow, using Excel concurrently by several users will not work. It starts to behave strangely and unreliably. This is documented somewhere on MSDN.

As a batch job that extracts data from the database and turns them into charts, Excel should work. Basically, if you can do it manually with Excel, it can be done automatically as well.

With "C API", do you mean the COM / automation interface to Excel? If yes, I recommend using C++ and all the Visual Studio tools and Microsoft C++ extensions because they make your life considerably easier.

Comment: The code will not be a web application.  Rather it will be an application that write/posts to a web page using an MS Excel file as it's data source.